# Apache rewrite condition to fall back when css doesn't exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I need a rule in Apache that redirects not-found CSS files to another location based on their names in another folder. Like this:

- **Request**: `localhost/css/nonexistent.css`
- **Response**: `localhost/css/g/nonexistent.css`

If the CSS exists, just serve it like normal:

- **Request**: `localhost/css/existent.css`
- **Response**: `localhost/css/existent.css`

My project is on CakePHP which comes with the following rules by default:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I mention it because whatever the new rule is, it should not break Cake's rules.

Thanks for the help.

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that the `css/g/` file is an alias for a script (inside the Cake MVC stack) that **g**enerates the new css file and echoes it. Answers so far seem to do the redirection fine, but then it doesn't find the `css/g/file.css` either because it really doesn't exist.

Comment: It should be noted that (as far as I understand that RewriteRule), the RewriteCond will never be reached, and can be deleted. This is because the Rule line will match any request (`^(.*)$`) and is flagged with [L] (last rule, stop processing). This means: 1. you can remove the last line (RewriteCond...) and 2. the solution to this question belongs *between* the RewriteEngine line and the existing RewriteRule line, and should not have a [L] flag unless you want the requests to *not* go through Cake (looks like Cake wants them all, that's pretty common).

Comment: @ctrahey My bad, I pasted the wrong set of rules for Cake, I just edited the question with the real ones. Thanks for your comment, though, it clears up a couple of things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try first checking if the /css/g/ css file exists:

```
# Make sure it doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Make sure this is a request for a css file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css/(.*)\.css$
# See if the /g/ version exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/css/g/%1.css -f
# rewrite if all conditions satisfied
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /css/g/$1 [L]
```

The **%1** in the 3rd condition backreferences the filename (sans .css extension) matched in the previous `RewriteCond`.

---

EDIT:

If the file css file is actually generated, then skip the checking of /g/ version and just pass it to the controller:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css/(.*)\.css$
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ index.php/css/g/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Notice that the framework in use gobbles up every request (as is too common)... so our rules must come before, and *should not* include the [L] flag (to comply with the framework's expectations).

Comment: @jon-lin thanks, I'll try that, please note that I pasted the wrong set of rules for cake, my bad. I just edited the question with the right ones.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a rewrite rule adapted from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890711/htaccess-file-redirect-if-not-exists-remote-file-upload) and [the Apache mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

The gist is: If the request is for a path that starts with `/css/`,get the filesystem path of the requested file and check if it exists. If id doesn't, rewrite the URL for your deeper directory. This should be placed *before* the rules you posted in your question.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) /css/g/$1
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to do the redirection but it fails to find the other file because (I forgot to mention this and just add it as an edit to the q) that `css/g/whatever.css` is an alias for a script inside Cake's MVC stack, ie, it points to `/profiles/styles/whatever`, so the request is served by an `styles` action in the `Profiles` controller.

Comment: It's working now, `RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) /css/g/$1` should be `RewriteRule ^css/(.*) /css/g/$1` thanks again